# Google Cloud Storage fees

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

I got this email from google today:

> Hello Google Cloud Storage User, Please be advised that, beginning
>   July 14, 2015, Google will begin charging the following fees for
>   Google Cloud Storage: $0.01 per GB of data transferred between buckets
>   located in different regions of the same continent Egress rates per GB
>   of data transferred between buckets located on different continents
>   Until then, you will be able to view your current usage in the billing
>   details for your project in order to help you estimate the impact of
>   these changes on your monthly spend. For additional information and
>   examples of this billing charge, please visit
>   https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-regions
>   -- The Google Cloud Storage Team Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043 You have received this mandatory
>   service announcement to update you about important changes to Google
>   Cloud Platform or your account.

So as a developer I have few projects that I support for my client. Should I remove them. Because as I understood I will pay for each 1GB $0.01, and if my customers make many transferring operation, it can be expensive for me =)

Also here is information about transferring:
[image]

So as I see they are $0.00, so my question for what I pay then?

Comment: By customer do you mean "someone paying to use my service(s)"?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith, I mena those are my client, I develop for then few iOS apps that use google drive access.

Comment: As the deveoper, only you know or should know if you are using cloud storage and if it applies to you.

Comment: Hi Matrosov. I should point out that asterisk at the end of $0.00 refers to the large blue box immediately under that section that begins "Promotional pricing through July 13, 2015" and proceeds to describe the manner in which that value will change in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming but fees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charges of which you speak are no different in nature than any other Google Cloud Storage charges. Just as your cloud project pays for storing objects or for bandwidth when serving objects from Google, it will now also be charged for bandwidth when copying objects between regions or continents.

Comment: ok, how can I pay for it? I think there is no payment option I set for google, so I've not added any cards and etc.

Comment: You need to set up and enable billing by going to your project in the Developers Console, click on the gearbox icon on the top right and select 'Project billing settings'. Then you'll need to click on 'Enable billing' and enter your billing info if you haven't done so already.

Comment: so if I understood, as a developer I pay for transaction between my users, I mean like sending files (upload/download traffic).

Comment: Hi Matrosov, a quick clarification of how billing works in GCS. All buckets belong to some project. All projects have some owners. The owners of a project pay for all operations involving any buckets belonging to their projects, including storage and network egress. You cannot create a bucket unless you already have billing enabled, and so if you do not already have a credit card on file, you most likely are not the owner of any buckets.