# Should I pay for Google Drive SDK for iOS

Tags: google-drive-api

Some times ago I received a message that developer will responsible to pay for data transfer using Google Drive SDK for iOS.

Is this still actual, how to calculate a price for it? As I understood if many users will download huge data via google drive storage, it will be expensive for me as developer using SDK.

Comment: It's rather impossible. Maybe someone made a joke? Can you find it anywhere in the internet?

Comment: @Vive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686983/google-cloud-storage-fees what do you think?

Comment: @Vive, or cloud storage and SDK are different?

Comment: As far as I understood, you only pay to move the content between the buckets in different continents. It's not that you pay to transfer to enduser. Anyway, I don't fully understand the situation and I won't comment it any more, as these are just my guesses.

Answer (score 0):

your linked question is about google cloud storage. that is untelated to google drive which has no cost to the developer if you are storing files in the user's drives.

Comment: ok, got it, because I found that message some, so as a developer I should don't mind about some prices and can use Google Drive iOS SDK without any worries. Right?